# gdb core dump opening failrue

Tags: c++, linux, crash, gdb

I am trying to open kernel core dump file. And what I am getting:

```
gdb app core.23605
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-32.el5)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/Development/Projects/app...done.
"/home/Development/Projects/core.23605" is not a core dump: File format not recognized


ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7616
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7616
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What generated the core dump?

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to debug a 64-bit core file?  Looks like you have 32-bit GDB.

Comment: It's "ELF 32-bit LSB core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style".

Comment: The core dump was generated automatically after segfault.

Comment: Perhaps the core file got truncated/corrupted somehow, or maybe you don't have read permissions on it (or on a directory leading up to it)?

Comment: @twalberg, I do have the permissions.

Comment: I just made a tiny test project that crushes with segfaut, the dumpfile was opened normally, so the problem isn't connected with gdb.

Answer (score 0):

> ... core.23605 is not a core dump

This most often happens when the core file is transferred from one machine to another via `ftp` in `ASCII` mode.

Comment: Not my case, I tried to open it in the same machine where it was created.